# Evaluate the number of different numbers one can write, having at one's disposal n digits of a q-ary system.

Tags: combinatorics, number-systems

I am working on Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I and I am stuck on a problem in section 2.2. The problem asks me to evaluate the number of different numbers one can write with n digits of a q-ary system. The answer given is $q ^ {\frac{n}{q}}$, which surprises me because I was wondering if $q ^ n$ should be the obvious answer. Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised too. The answer seems to require that $q$ divide $n$. Are you sure you have stated the whole question and its context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part (b) of a three part question and I think interpretation of what the question is asking may need the whole question to be considered.  Part (c) talks about $f(x)=x^{n/x}$ so the given answer to (b) is unlikely to an error but may be affected by what the words were intended to mean

Part (a) is

> How  many  different   numbers  can  one  define  using  $20$  decimal  digits   (for   example,  two  ranks  with  $10$ possible  digits  in  each)?  Answer  the  same  question  for  the  binary  system.  Which  system  does  a  comparison  of  the  results  favor  in  terms  of  efficiency?

and the answer to the first part is presumably $10^2=100$ as there are $10$ possibilities in the *tens* rank and $10$ possibilities in the *units* rank.  With $20$ binary digits (ten  ranks  with  $2$ possible  digits  in  each) the answer is presumably $2^{10} = 1024$ making binary more able to represent different numbers

So in (b) the number of ranks is presumably $\frac{n}{q}$ (at least when $n$ is a multiple of $q$) and, with $q$ digits available for each rank, this makes the total number of possibilities $q^{n/q}$

Comment: Do you think this is a poorly written question? If there are 10 possible digits in two ranks, I would describe that as 2 digits, I do not know any sensible interpretation which makes that 20 digits.

Comment: @MikeEarnest On its own, part (b) looks peculiar, but I think what is desired is reasonably clear in context, especially since the question contains the suggested answer.  It may be an issue of translation from Russian.  But I have seen sports [flip-over scoreboards](http://www.cra-cricket.co.uk/cricket-scoreboards/portascore-scoreboard.html) which ten different digits for each position so there is some sort of interpretation that fits

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpful!